# Что означает "There is 1 zombie process" и что с ним делать?

Tags: linux, процесс

Залогинился на удаленную машину. Вижу следующую строку в приветственном сообщении.

> There is 1 zombie process.

[Насколько я понял](https://serverfault.com/q/390202/310873), это означает, что какой-то процесс завершил работу, но не закрылся и не освободил ресурсы. Хотелось бы лучше понять проблему:

- Как можно его обнаружить? Сейчас я угадал, но нужен стабильный метод.
- Как можно узнать причины его появления? Есть какие-нибудь логи? Может, по имеющемуся процессу можно что-либо понять?

Если это важно, ubuntu 14.04, sudo есть.

Дополнение: меня не устраивает метод «просто подождать», т.к. есть сервис, который должен работать всегда — и подвис он или кто-то из его детей. Он подстрахован monit'ом, но тот не распознал зомбификацию и не перезагрузил.

Comment: *Как можно узнать причины его появления?* - родитель его (еще) не рипнул, возможно, рипнет позднее. При завершении родителя все дочерние процессы будут усыновлены родительским процессом родителя, где, скорее всего, всё и разрулится. Сам зомби процесс занимает, насколько помню, всего ничего (буквально саму запись в таблице), поэтому пока нет прогрессии, все должно быть в порядке.

Comment: *всё и разрулится* — все возникавшие в моей практике zombie-процессы (а случались они очень редко и было это очень давно) продолжали существовать до перезагрузки системы.

Comment: Замби - плод ошибки в родителе, он просто забыл про ребенка. Если родитель сильно занят и не реагирует на сигналы, то он может просто _вовремя_ не забрать код завершения. так что на очень короткое время `ps` может и в полностью исправной системе. Но выход убрать зомби только один - убить родителя. Так что придется учить монит понимать зомби, узнавать родителей ...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin родительский процесс-то прибивался?

Comment: Ну и комментарий на всякий: если на хосте используется докер, вполне возможно, проблема в нем, т.к. процессом #1 в контейнере является не init, и процесс #1 может не уметь рипать чайлдов. Это довольно неприятный случай, но пересоздание (не уверен насчет рестарта) контейнера должно решить проблему.

Comment: @Etki, боюсь ошибиться, но, насколько я помню теорию, zombie и возникают от того, что родительский процесс, «скончавшись», их не «прибил».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в этом случае они наследуются процессом-дедом после смерти родителя, который рипает их, если считает нужным - [When a process loses its parent, init becomes its new parent. init periodically executes the wait system call to reap any zombies with init as parent.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

Comment: @Etki: спасибо, у меня пока без докера, но будет полезно знать о такой проблеме.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Зомби в операционных системах UNIX называют завершившиеся процессы, код завершения которых не забрал родительский процесс. Зомби не потребляют никаких ресурсов, память и файловые дескрипторы таких процессов уже освобождены. Остается только запись в таблице процессов, которая занимает несколько десятков байт памяти. Так что единичный зомби процесс на систему никак не влияет. НО он явный индикатор того, что у какого то процесса в системе что то пошло не так.

Поиск зомби:

```
ps -axho state,pid,ppid | grep Z | sed 's/./ps/' | sh
```

Данная команда покажет все зомби процессы и их родителей (тестировалась под linux, под другими *nix возможны другие ключи у команды ps).

Убить зомби можно только перезапуском родительского процесса. kill -9 самого процесса-зомби и чеснок обычно не помогают. Если появление зомби разовое явление, то возможно проще на факт его появления забить.

Что бы понять почему именно появился зомби надо смотреть исходники породившего его процесса и возможно самого зомби. Часто это одна и та же программа. Любой процесс, выполняющий `fork`, т.е. запускающий дочерние процессы должен уметь забирать код их завершения, делается это вызовом `wait` и/или `waitpid`. Для начала надо просмотреть исходники на наличие функций группы wait, а так же наличие функции-обработчика сигнала SIGCHLD (обработчик устанавливается вызовом `signal` и функций для работы с сигналами потоков). Если родитель не использует функции группы wait, то возможно при его нормальной работе завершение дочерних процессов разработчик вообще не ожидал. Если это так - то причина образования зомби - незапланированное завершение процесса потомка в следствие какой либо ошибки. Дать рекомендаций как это искать и лечить невозможно. Можно только посоветовать добавить в родительский поток обработку CHLD, забор кода завершения с помощью wait и логирование факта завершения потомка. И дальше запуск потомка под отладчик и т.п. ...

Вариант 2: родительский процесс использует `wait`, но зомби все равно появляются. Копать в сторону того, какая разновидность wait используется, если waitpid, которая проверяет завершение конкретных потомков, то смотреть откуда она берет проверяемые pid, возможно в процессе работы какие то pid потомков теряются и программа про них забывает. Может программа в какой то момент запрещает обработку сигналов и забывает восстановить обработку, после прохождения критического участка. Опять же - вариантов очень много, но сосредоточены они вокруг обработчика SIGCHLD и функций `wait`.

Вариант 3: родительский процесс умеет обрабатывать и готов правильно обработать завершение своих потомков. Но зацикливается в другом месте программы или засыпает на системном вызове, например чтения с сетевого диска, который стал недоступен и при этом прерывание по SIGCHLD запрещено. В этом случае надо разбираться с причинами его зависания. Кстати, отсутствие доступа к каким либо ресурсам, типа сетевых дисков (или при выходе из строя физического диска) - довольно частая причина массового появления зомби.

Каких либо специальных логов в системе, где можно было бы увидеть хоть какую то информацию по появляющимся зомби не существует. Следы можно найти только в логах той программы, которая их порождает, при их наличии.

Comment: Да-да, там именно форки. Спасибо, буду копать. Попробую воспроизвести ситуацию с появлением зомби.